# Refreshing XAML GUI in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, xaml, user-interface

I am building a GUI for some of the tasks we need to do (mostly for the people with no powershell knowledge, so they don't have to run commands etc).

Basically I have a couple of windows where they can enter input or hit some buttons.
Now I have to open them up in a new window every time they hit next or continue.

Is there a way to clear my current window and load in the elements needed for the next step?

Using tabs is not an option as the options/textboxes/buttons etc. are dependent on which button they hit in their previous screen.

I tried stuff like `$window.clear()` but that doesn't work.

What ideally would happen is that I can generate the window and then use functions to dynamically change the layout of the windows and add/remove the necessary components.

Anyone has any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: To be honest, I'd use tabs to do what you are doing, and maybe hide the tab bar. That way you can have several screen layouts on various tabs, and then have your script determine which tab to make active depending on what options they chose.

Comment: After some looking around, I figured it is better to use tabs. I necessary I can even make the tabs invisible so that does the trick as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is hiding/unhiding elements?

update-window -Control (element) -Property Visibility -Value Hidden